# Two services with different host but same alias not working wildfly

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, wildfly

We're using `Wildfly-17.0.1`
and we have 2 spring-boot microservices which are being deployed as war on wildfly

- service-a.war
- service-b.war

We have `jboss-web.xml` in both services under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`

service-a.war

```
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>/</context-root>
  <virtual-host>default-host</virtual-host>
</jboss-web>
```

service-b.war

```
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>/</context-root>
  <virtual-host>b-host</virtual-host>
</jboss-web>
```

standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:9.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="other" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.undertow.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
    <buffer-cache name="default" />
    <server name="default-server">
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true" />
        <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="UndertowRealm" enable-http2="true" />
        <host name="default-host" alias="alias" default-web-module="service-a.war" />
        <host name="b-host" alias="alias" default-web-module="service-b.war" />
    </server>
    ...
</subsystem>
```

Above alias is the machine name

In the **server.log** we see below message when both applications are deployed

```
 ...
 Registered web context: '/' for server 'default-server'
 ...
 Registered web context: '/' for server 'default-server'
```

But when we try to access both services only one of the service seems to be working, other gives

```
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>404 - Not Found</body></html>
```

We tried giving different context-root, and we saw this in log

```
 ...
 Registered web context: '/a' for server 'default-server'
 ...
 Registered web context: '/b' for server 'default-server'
```

but still only one works and other gives 404.

It works when we give different alias for both the hosts

Why giving the same alias for different hosts doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I **think** the string you put as virtualhost in jboss-web.xml must match the **alias** (not the **name**) in standalone conf

Instead of

```
<host name="b-host" alias="alias" default-web-module="service-b.war" />
```

Try with:

```
<host name="vhost2" alias="b-host" default-web-module="service-b.war" />
```